# Webrtc: How to negotiate tracks without knowing number ahead of time?

Tags: webrtc, sdp

I am trying to implement multiple video streams via a single RTCPeerConnection in WebRTC. I am aware that this has varying support in browsers but things have been working in the latest Chrome and Firefox. Anyways, I am currently able to have multiple video tracks working by using RTCPeerConnection.addTransceiver() to add multiple video tracks before sending the SDP offer. My problem is this: the browser may not know ahead of time how many video channels are available on the remote device. Currently if I setup the same number of transceivers on the browser and my remote device, things negotiate alright, but if there is a difference the browser throws an error when it encounters an SDP answer with a different number of tracks than it offered. Is there any way to negotiate this via the WebRTC protocol, or would I have to setup some kind of external API that can report how many tracks are available?

Answer (score 2):

For 2 video tracks, just using regular RTCPeerConnection.addTrack works for me:

```js
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection()

...

const webcamStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: true});
const screenStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia();

webcamStream.getVideoTracks().forEach((track) => pc.addTrack(track));
screenStream.getVideoTracks().forEach((track) => pc.addTrack(track));
```

Using the above, `pc.createOffer` generates an SDP offer message with 3 m= fields; 1 for audio, and 2 for video. Then on the other end, when I `createAnswer` it generates a proper SDP answer message with those 3 medias and establishes the connection.

If you want more tracks than that, I am not sure what would be the behavior of the code above, but I believe it will depend on the webrtc implementation of the client.

That said, I think the safest way to get around this would be to include how many video tracks are incoming through your signaling server at the time you send the offer. Then you just `addTransceivers` as many times as you need when you receive it.